# laravel routes folder missing after install using composer

Tags: php, laravel, cmd, composer-php

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel
```

I  use  this  code in  my  pc cmd  to  install  laravel. after install i saw route  folder is  missing. but in  laravel documentation  say there should be  route folder.  I'm  new  to  laravel but  um  OK with codeignitere.  so i need a  help to  solve  this  issue.

**This is screenshot  of  my cmd  that  will  help you to get  idea about  my issue**
[image: This is screenshot of my cmd that will help you to get idea about my issue]

Thanks.

Comment: Install again or show us the end of your command screen.

Comment: @sachinkumar i fix it Sir. Thanks  for  your  comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were installed laravel 5.2, so the routes.php in "app/Http". See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.2/app/Http, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2

Comment: i fix it Sir. Thanks for your answer